# Adding a listview to each element in a listview?

Tags: java, mysql, listview, javafx

I am trying to attach a listview to each of the elemnts in another listview and the listview is connected to an sql database. So you pick a value in the listview and another listview pops up. But i cant figure out how to attach them with the listener.
This i what i have so far, hope you understand my question.
[Its supposed to look like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TCyS1.png)

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}
private ArrayList<String> getArtister () {
    ArrayList<String> artister = new ArrayList<>();
    try (Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(
            "jdbc:mysql://vhost6.lnu.se:23306/1ik013v20-12?useSSL=false",
            "1ik013v20-12", "aubergine")) {
        Statement statement = conn.createStatement();
        ResultSet result = statement.executeQuery("SELECT Namn FROM artist");
        while (result.next()) {
            artister.add(result.getString(1));
        }
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        System.out.println("Something went wrong...");
    }
    return artister;
}
private ArrayList<String> getLåtar () {
    ArrayList<String> låtar = new ArrayList<>();
    try (Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(
            "jdbc:mysql://vhost6.lnu.se:23306/1ik013v20-12?useSSL=false",
            "1ik013v20-12", "aubergine")) {
        Statement statement = conn.createStatement();
        ResultSet result = statement.executeQuery("SELECT Namn FROM album WHERE Artist = 'Bob Dylan'");
        while (result.next()) {
            låtar.add(result.getString(1));
        }
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        System.out.println("Something went wrong...");
    }
    return låtar;
}


private ArrayList<String> getLåtar1 () {
    ArrayList<String> låtar = new ArrayList<>();
    try (Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(
            "jdbc:mysql://vhost6.lnu.se:23306/1ik013v20-12?useSSL=false",
            "1ik013v20-12", "aubergine")) {
        Statement statement = conn.createStatement();
        ResultSet result = statement.executeQuery("SELECT Namn FROM album WHERE Artist = 'Bob Marley'");
        while (result.next()) {
            låtar.add(result.getString(1));
        }
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        System.out.println("Something went wrong...");
    }
    return låtar;
}
private ArrayList<String> getLåtar2 () {
    ArrayList<String> låtar = new ArrayList<>();
    try (Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(
            "jdbc:mysql://vhost6.lnu.se:23306/1ik013v20-12?useSSL=false",
            "1ik013v20-12", "aubergine")) {
        Statement statement = conn.createStatement();
        ResultSet result = statement.executeQuery("SELECT Namn FROM album WHERE Artist = 'Bob Marley'");
        while (result.next()) {
            låtar.add(result.getString(1));
        }
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        System.out.println("Something went wrong...");
    }
    return låtar;
}
private ArrayList<String> getLåtar3 () {
    ArrayList<String> låtar = new ArrayList<>();
    try (Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(
            "jdbc:mysql://vhost6.lnu.se:23306/1ik013v20-12?useSSL=false",
            "1ik013v20-12", "aubergine")) {
        Statement statement = conn.createStatement();
        ResultSet result = statement.executeQuery("SELECT Namn FROM album WHERE Artist = 'Bob Marley'");
        while (result.next()) {
            låtar.add(result.getString(1));
        }
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        System.out.println("Something went wrong...");
    }
    return låtar;
}

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    BorderPane pane = new BorderPane();
    ListView art = new ListView();
    art.getItems().addAll(getArtister());
    ListView alb = new ListView();
    ListView alb1 = new ListView();
    ListView alb2 = new ListView();
    ListView alb3 = new ListView();


    art.getSelectionModel().selectedIndexProperty().addListener(ov -> {

    });

    Text text = new Text("MUSIK");
    text.setFont(new Font(20));
    text.setFill(Color.DARKBLUE);
    pane.setLeft(art);
    pane.setTop(text);
    BorderPane.setAlignment(art, Pos.CENTER_LEFT);
    BorderPane.setAlignment(text, Pos.TOP_LEFT);

    Scene scene = new Scene(pane, 500, 500);
    primaryStage.setTitle("Musiken");
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
}
```

}

Comment: always use latin characters when naming your methods and variables

Comment: sorry, new to the programming!

Comment: no worries. btw, your approach seems a bit unusual. You want to have 4 different lists for 4 different artists, right? What if you have 100 artists? You must think a bit more dynamic. You can have a single collection as Pair<String,String> whereas first string is Artist and second string is Album.

Comment: Alright i understand. I dont have to have 4 different lists, its just where i was at the moment. The intial thought was to have a two lists, one with the artists and one with the artists songs. And the artist  i pressed in the (artist)list detemined what the other list was supposed to show.

Comment: Did the solution work?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, try this. Create a new class like below

```
private class Vinyl
{
    String artist;
    List<String> listAlbums;
    
    public Vinyl(String artist) {
        this.artist = artist;
        listAlbums = new ArrayList<String>();
    }
    
    public void AddToListAlbums(String album)
    {
        listAlbums.add(album);
    }

    public String getArtist() {
        return artist;
    }

    public List<String> getListAlbums() {
        return listAlbums;
    }               
}
```

I just named it Vinyl. You can name it whatever you like.

Now returning to your main class, define a list of Vinyl globally. Only call these methods to fill your list.

```
List<Vinyl> listVinyl = new ArrayList<>();  

private void GetArtists () {
    
    try (Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(
            "jdbc:mysql://vhost6.lnu.se:23306/1ik013v20-12?useSSL=false",
            "1ik013v20-12", "aubergine")) {
        Statement statement = conn.createStatement();
        ResultSet result = statement.executeQuery("SELECT Namn FROM artist");
        while (result.next()) {
            listVinyl.add(new Vinyl(result.getString(1))); 
        }
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        System.out.println("Something went wrong...");
    }        
}   

private void GetAlbums () {      
    try (Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(
            "jdbc:mysql://vhost6.lnu.se:23306/1ik013v20-12?useSSL=false",
            "1ik013v20-12", "aubergine")) {
        Statement statement = conn.createStatement();
        ResultSet result = statement.executeQuery("SELECT Namn FROM album");
        
        Vinyl currentVinyl;
        String album = "";
        
        while (result.next()) {
            
            String artist = result.getString(1); // TODO you must correct the number. I don't know which field is it.
            
            currentVinyl = listVinyl.stream()
                    .filter(u -> u.artist.equals(artist))
                    .findAny()
                    .orElse(null);
            
            album = result.getString(2); // TODO you must correct the number. I don't know which field is it.               
            
            currentVinyl.AddToListAlbums(album);                
        }
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        System.out.println("Something went wrong...");
    }
}
```

Please be careful, there are 2 TODOs for you. Those are your field indexes. I don't know the structure of your database so I just wrote 1 and 2. Those must be the fields of your artist name and album name.

At the end of this, you will have only 1 collection that covers everything you need.

Comment: You're welcome. Please let me know if that works.

Comment: java naming conventions, please